USB device not recognized on Debian and missing /dev/ttyUSB
I am quite new to Linux. I have two BeagleBone Black PCs with Yantrr Vayu2 4G modem, running on Debian 10. I am connecting to the internet using the PPP protocol and rnet. On the first PC everything works fine. On the other one after a while all /dev/ttyUSBXX are missing. The modem is connected via USB cable but I think it is not recognized. I tried everything but nothing worked. I appreciate any help. Thank you!
I have tried disconnecting and rebooting multiple times, apt update and upgrade. I have run the udevadm monitor and disconnected and reconnected the modem. This is the output on PC1 (that works)
root@ES-23-001:/home/debian# sudo udevadm monitor -u
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [1392.179308] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1 (tty)
UDEV  [1392.267717] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/ttyUSB2/tty/ttyUSB2 (tty)
UDEV  [1392.321697] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1/ttyUSB1 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1392.352511] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0 (tty)
UDEV  [1392.406432] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1/ttyUSB1 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1392.424347] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.435601] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1392.445325] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/ttyUSB2 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1392.455814] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3/ttyUSB3/tty/ttyUSB3 (tty)
UDEV  [1392.473412] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/ttyUSB2 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1392.512199] remove   /devices/virtual/net/ppp0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [1392.529478] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1392.562879] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.581837] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.588271] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3/ttyUSB3 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1392.611817] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.624182] remove   /devices/virtual/net/ppp0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [1392.626737] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4/net/wwan0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [1392.640314] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.650454] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.652824] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3/ttyUSB3 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1392.658781] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4/net/wwan0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [1392.740723] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4/usbmisc/cdc-wdm0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [1392.743974] remove   /usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [1392.763394] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.777979] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.789570] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.817506] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.860212] remove   /devices/virtual/net/ppp0 (net)
UDEV  [1392.898065] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4/net/wwan0 (net)
UDEV  [1392.918675] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.923824] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.939208] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.943067] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.959512] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.974344] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.978512] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1392.995522] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1393.011458] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1393.024231] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1393.038080] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1393.041581] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1393.054691] unbind   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1393.061798] remove   /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1399.278232] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1399.330200] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1399.338557] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1399.350073] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1399.715314] add      /class/usbmisc (class)
UDEV  [1399.840265] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.084584] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.105553] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.149656] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.169643] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.199349] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.247247] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4/usbmisc/cdc-wdm0 (usbmisc)
UDEV  [1400.305731] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1/ttyUSB1 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1400.321751] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1400.387234] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3/ttyUSB3 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1400.422698] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/ttyUSB2 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1400.519200] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1/ttyUSB1/tty/ttyUSB1 (tty)
UDEV  [1400.548458] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1/ttyUSB1 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1400.643388] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0 (tty)
UDEV  [1400.655855] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.711817] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/ttyUSB0 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1400.759873] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.765887] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/ttyUSB2/tty/ttyUSB2 (tty)
UDEV  [1400.774009] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3/ttyUSB3/tty/ttyUSB3 (tty)
UDEV  [1400.787412] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/ttyUSB2 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1400.861183] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3/ttyUSB3 (usb-serial)
UDEV  [1400.872936] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1400.880331] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [1401.089989] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4/net/wwan0 (net)
UDEV  [1401.118058] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4/net/wwan0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [1401.125276] add      /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4/net/wwan0/queues/tx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [1401.145860] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.4 (usb)
UDEV  [1401.173397] bind     /devices/platform/ocp/47400000.usb/47401c00.usb/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1422.925708] add      /devices/virtual/net/ppp0 (net)
UDEV  [1422.952483] add      /devices/virtual/net/ppp0/queues/rx-0 (queues)
UDEV  [1422.981487] add      /devices/virtual/net/ppp0/queues/tx-0 (queues)

And this is on the nonworking PC:

I do not understand it, but there is no info about /dev/ttyUSB, so I think it could be a driver issue or something. And when I try the lsusb command the modem is listed there:  here But when I try to connect the /dev/ttyUSB3 is not there:   But on the first PC it is there: 
I just noticed that the device may not be connected due to the power limit, but I don't understand why it works on one PC but not on the other one...
[ 515.572532] usb 1-1.1: rejected 1 configuration due to insufficient available bus power
[ 515.572553] usb 1-1.1: no configuration chosen from 1 choice

Using the command:
echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.1/bConfigurationValue

helped, but I do not know if it is a good idea and I have to set it after every reboot.

hm... Did you check for the bMaxPower file value in /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.1/  or /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/ (bus number 1 port number 1).... is it the same as on the other computer.
